# how to use perl package have same name of module

Tags: perl

```
    package B;
    use Moose;

    has 'b' => (
        is => 'ro',
        isa => 'Str',
        default => 'Hello',
   );

    package main;                                                                                                                                         
    my $b = B->new;
```

i use this code , but the error is :

**Can't locate object method "new" via package "B" at t.pl line 30.**

i know the **B** module has installed, 
so how can i refer the **B** in my file , but not the **B** module ?

Comment: -1, Your code does not result in that error. Please fix.

Comment: @ikegami My mistake.  I removed those comments.

Answer (score 4):

"B" is the name of an existing core module. Don't name your module "B".

Comment: yes, that's right. i know. that's the problem i want you to solve

Comment: I don't understand. What problems are you having renaming your module?

Comment: Sounds like what you want to do is hack your script in such a way that your B module gets loaded instead of the existing perl B module. I would recommend you not do that hack. It will very likely make your script unstable.

Comment: I've already told you the code in your question does not have any error. If it has nothing to do with the name "B", then use a different module name when you add a demonstration of your problem to your question. I'm not going to guess again.